Spring app not picking up application profiles in Docker Swarm
I have the following setup (simplified) - an Eureka discovery service and an auth service.
Assume Eureka is configured correctly and works (because it does, it's healthy, it's registering services, it works both locally and in Docker swarm).
The auth service, however, is not picking up it's application-prod.yml config at all in Docker Swarm (launched via compose) and is still trying to connect to the localhost:8761 port, when it should connect to discovery:8761. I can see the profile being loaded as 'prod' in the logs.
Here are the configs for the auth service (and the Dockerfile):
application.yml
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true

server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  application:
    name: auth
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: configserver
      name: ${spring.application.name}
      fail-fast: false
      retry:
        initialInterval: 5000
        maxInterval: 15000
        maxAttempts: 10
  config:
    import: 'optional:configserver:'

application-dev.yml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

application-prod.yml
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://discovery:8761/eureka/

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod

build.gradle.kts
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.3"

dependencies {
    // Spring Authorization Server
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    // For JWT support
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5")

    // Communication
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")

    // Dev dependencies
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    // Cloud capacity
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

Dockerfile
FROM emilavramov/java-temurin-21-gradle AS builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches

COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle.kts build.gradle.kts
COPY settings.gradle.kts settings.gradle.kts

RUN gradle dependencies --no-build-cache --parallel --no-daemon

COPY . .

RUN gradle :auth:bootJar --no-build-cache --parallel --no-daemon

# Stage 2: Create a minimal deployment image with just the JRE
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre-alpine AS deploy

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/auth/build/libs/auth-*.jar /app/auth.jar

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/auth.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=prod"]


When I run the auth service locally with bootRun --spring.profiles.active=prod, it picks it up and tries to connect to the non-existing discovery:8761, when I run it with dev, it correctly connects to localhost:8761 and registers with Eureka (also discovers the configserver I ommited to simplicity and pulls the default and def configs from it).
In Docker Swarm, however, it does not work.
this is my docker-compose.yml (omitted some services for simplicity)
services:
  discovery:
    image: discovery:latest
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: discovery/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-network
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: "wget -T5 -qO- http://localhost:8761/actuator/health | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s

  auth:
    image: auth:latest
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: auth/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - discovery
      - configserver
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: "wget -T5 -qO- http://localhost:9000/actuator/health | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 25s

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: overlay

I've been bashing my head against this for a few days with no result, my configserver is correctly picking up the application-prod.yml and connecting to discovery (eureka configs are identical to auth service), but auth service does not - it's still trying to connect to localhost, despite being in prod mode. The application files are in the JAR (on the container) and are in the classpath.
Anyone have any ideas?
